# How do I call my namespaced class from the lib directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a class that's 3 levels deep in my lib directory that I'm trying to call but I get an uninitialized constant error. My class and directory structure looks like this:

file name: lib/my_module/my_second_module/my_third_module/my_class.rb

```
module my_module
  module my_second_module
    module my_third_module
      class my_class
        def self.something
          do something...
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to call this class using the rails console but it returns 'uninitialized constant my_module'. I run this command and get this error:

```
MyModule::MySecondModule::MyThirdModule::MyClass.something
```

Also I've include the following in config/application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/my_module/**/"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by using another method to load my modules in the lib folder. For some reason, the way I had did not load my lib files:

```
config.to_prepare do
  Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../lib/my_module/**/*.rb")) do |c|
    Rails.configuration.cache_classes ? require(c) : load(c)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `::MyModule::MySecondModule::MyThirdModule::MyClass.something`

Comment: It's still complaining about that first module. - NameError: uninitialized constant MyModule